# dictionary - same key but have to find the highest value of the key

Tags: python

```
x = {"January": 5, "January": 30, "March": 12, "March": 20}
```

I have to code a function where i have a few dates from several months. Now i have to only return the date with the higher value

Comment: from each month*

Comment: You can't have a dictionary with duplicated keys can you?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a dictionary with the same key multiple times.

Your dictionary will only hold the last value of each key.

```py
>>> x = {"January": 5, "January": 30, "March": 12, "March": 20}
>>> x
{'January': 30, 'March': 20}
```

What's your original data? For example you can use a dictionary with lists as value.

```py
>>> x = {"January": [5, 30], "March": [12, 20]}
```

Comment: i have a dictionary = {"August": 30, "May": 10, "May": 20, "February": 15} and my function has to return "Your appointment for May is on the 20.". Can i iterate somehow trough the dictionary and find out which value from the key May is higher?

Comment: @Lstk You can't have a dictionary with a key which shows up multiple times. Only the last value will be saved in the dictionary.

Comment: @Lstk How do you get this dictionary. Are the values in a file or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

A key within a dict is unique and can only have one value.
If you want to store multiple values I suggest you store them in a container, e.g. a list.

```
>>> x = {"January": [5, 30], "March": [12,20]}
```

Then you can retrieve the highest value using max(or lowest using min):

```
>>> max(x["January"])
30
```

And update values:

```
>>> x["January"].append(6)
```